# Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find BB Data.xlsx . Is it possible it was moved,renamed or deleted?

Tags: excel, vba

I was writing a number of macros in order to pull data from multiple other files and print the data on a single destination file.
The macros were working smoothly until I started coding "module 7".

The macro breaks at line 4 indicated below:

```
Dim B_PWBR as Workbook
Set B_PWBR = Workbooks("PWBR Destin.xlsm")
Dim BB_WPI as Workbook
Set BB_WPI = Workbooks.Open("BB Data.xlsx")
```

The Error message indicated is:

```
Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find filename.xlsx . Is it possible it was moved,renamed or deleted?
```

`BB Data.xlsx` is the source file from which I am copying data

`PWBR Destin.xlsx` is the output file to which I am copying the data and the file in which the macros reside.

**Note:** All the other 6 modules were working fine before this ( and contains similar code), but after adding module 7, none of the modules work and they all break upon reaching the code line 4 which opens a different file in each module.

Have any of you encountered a similar issue before? If yes, how can I resolve it? Any help in this matter will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("BB Data.xlsx")` - to open workbook you should put entire path, but not only file name

Comment: Hi simoco,please note that all the files are in the same folder which is why I did not specify the path in the code. I had used the same approach in all the other modules and it seemed to be working fine at that time. Could not specifying the path really be the root cause?

Comment: Have you tried removing module 7 to test if it helps?

Comment: I tried removing module 7 but the problem persisted. I then implemented @simoco 's (thank you sim) solution and hard-coded the file path and it worked! I now face a different problem. I want others to be able to run these macros on their systems by placing all their files in a single folder. Hard coding the file path will cause issues. Is there any work-around for this new problem?

Comment: `Is there any work-around for this new problem?` - yes - `Set BB_WPI = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\BB Data.xlsx")`